# Unit testing when the returned value is a mock expectation

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

So I have a method that looks something like this:

`public Foo method() {
    ...
    return service.get();
}`

`service` is an external dependency of the class.

My test code:

`Foo mockServiceResponse = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
when(service.get()).thenReturn(mockServiceResponse);`

In my unit test I inject a mock created with Mockito and set a `when` for `service.get()` so my question is, how do I test the return value of `method`?
If I just check if `mockServiceResponse` is equal to `method()` the test doesnt check much since if someone changes `method` to:

`public Foo method() {
    ...
    Foo f = service.get();
    f.setId(null);
    return f;
}`

My test will still pass, which is obviously wrong, so how should I test this?

**CLARIFICATION:** What I want to test is that `method` doesnt change the object returned from `service.get()` (meaning, I want the second stub to fail my test), problem is mock objects just ignore methods called on them (like `setId()`) without failing the test.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. all you have to establish is that the result of the method call is the thing that you told the mock to return.

Comment: 1. Why are you mocking the response, instead of creating a real one and checking this real one is returned. 2. A test is just that: a test. It's not supposed to be a mathematical proof and check for every weird unrealistic thing the code could possibly do. What if someone also changes the test anyway? 3. If really you want to keep it this way, you can use https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.22.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verifyZeroInteractions-java.lang.Object...-

Comment: It is not clear to me, what you really want to test.  I get the impression (but this is an assumption only), what you really want to test is the logic within the code represented by the ellipsis "..." that precedes the return statement - while the way you mock the service.get() call will only make your tests see the content of the mock, but give no insights whether the other code of the method is correct.  Is this what your question is aiming at?

Comment: added clarification, hopefully its better now

Answer (score 0):

You'll do something like:

```
Service service = mock(Service.class);
Foo aResponse = new Foo(1);
when(service.get()).thenReturn(aResponse);

MyClass subject = new MyClass(service);

Foo result = subject.method();
assertNull(result.getId());
```

Comment: @jwismar I am in a similar situation, but does this unit test worth it? It is not really testing anything other than the value returned from mock. Can we say that it is "too simple to test"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mockito's [`verifyNoMoreInteractions`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verifyNoMoreInteractions-java.lang.Object...-) or [`verifyZeroInteractions`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verifyZeroInteractions-java.lang.Object...-) to assert that no calls were made to the service response object.

```
@Test
public void should_not_mutate_response() {
    // given
    Service mockService = Mockito.mock(Service.class);
    Foo mockServiceResponse = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
    when(mockService.get()).thenReturn(mockServiceResponse);

    SubjectUnderTest subjectUnderTest = new SubjectUnderTest(mockService);

    // when
    Foo result = subjectUnderTest.method();

    //then
    Mockito.verifyZeroInteractions(mockServiceResponse);
}
```

Or if you expect some particular interactions with the response object after all:

```
@Test
public void should_set_id_on_response() {
    // given
    ...

    // when
    ...

    // then
    Mockito.verify(mockServiceResponse).setId(ArgumentMatchers.anyInt());
    Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockServiceResponse);
}
```